# Bad Access Challenges

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center, challenge-response

When a user's friend challenges his highscore, and the user beats it, it replies with a new challenge (By apple, not programmed). The other user gets the challenge, but the sender's game immediately crashes with Bad Access on this line if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onScoresSubmitted:)]) from this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/23189/whats-new-with-game-center-in-ios-6

Any ideas?

Comment: You may also consider posting in their official forum thread for that tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums//viewtopic.php?f=20&t=5167

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your _delegate is not random garbage value at this point?.

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onScoresSubmitted:)])
```

Make sure the client (delegate) who use the callBack clean the server delegate so that the callBack is not done anymore.

This can be done in two way:

1. A: make from the sever side a retain of the delegate (but it's not a
   delegate relationship anymore).
2. B: assign to nil the delegate pointer when the delegate client
   doesn't need the service anymore.

Here a common error, because of a bad implementation:

```
ADelegateClient* client = [ADelegateClient new];
[SingletonService service].delegate = (id<SingletonServiceDelegate>)client;
[client release];
// you must [SingletonService service].delegate = nil; Since
// [SingletonService service] cannot know the delegate is not pointing to something valid anymore
[[SingletonService service] makeStuffWillCauseCallBackToDelegate];
```

I didn't read Ray code, if your problem is not similar to this, then i look deep further. But i'm 99% sure it's related to a deallocated pointer problem;